# SMB/NFS Backend for SVN Server -- Permissions Errors

Tags: nfs, svn, server-message-block, cifs

**Ubuntu 16**

**Apache2**

**SVN 1.9.3**

I created an SVN server and set the repo root to reside on an NFS mount (mounted with root).  Users on other machines were able to connect to the repo and do a checkout but when they attempt to commit, they get a permissions error.

```
Can't open file '/mnt/W/testrepo/firstrepo/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied
```

Normally I would do a `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data` to fix this issue but as far as I know you cannot do this on an NFS share.

I also attempted to use SMB for the backend with mount options: `username=username,password=password,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm` but got the same permissions error when trying to commit.

Is there a way to mount the NFS share as www-data?  Or some other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Mounted in /etc/fstab instead of mounting with a command and now there are no permissions issues.